# Actionscript 3 E4X working with namespace values in XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, namespaces, e4x

I am building an application using Action script 3 I am retrieving some XML from the web however the node names are mms:Image mms:Results etc my action script compiler is throwing an error becuase it is not expecting to see the semi colon in the node name. How to I access the nodes?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are XML namespaces and they can be a pain to use. Have a look at the Adobe documentation on [Using XML namespaces](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6c.html).

Basically you have to get the namespace:

```
var mmsNS:Namespace = message.namespace("mms");

// alternatively for nested namespaces:

var mmsNS:Namespace = new Namespace("mms", " ... url of namespace ... ");
```

And then use it when you want to get the nodes that it is applied to:

```
var data:XML = message.@mmsNS::Results;
```

A shortcut if all of your xml is in a particular namespace is to set the default namespace:

```
default xml namespace = mmsNs;
```

**edit:** The XML namespace you are trying to access must be declared within the XML fragment:

```
<root xmlns:mms="http://example.com/mms">
    <mms:someNode someAttr="someVal" />
</root>
```

Have a look at the w3c docs for [XML Namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) to ensure your document is well-formed (maybe even pass it through a validator).

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried it out and i keep getting an error of "illegal value for namespace" any ideas?

Comment: Also how do i find out what the url of the namespace is?

Comment: The xml namespace must be declared within the XML. I'll add an example.